# UISearchController overlaps UITableView which makes me unable to present detailed ViewController for cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I made a `UIViewController`that contains `UISearchController` and a `UITableView`. The UITableView initially presents all results that are then going to be filtered through the `UISearchController` whenever the user starts typing something. Clicking on each cell should link to a detailed page. Although this works when the user hasn't yet started typing, it doesn't work anymore once the user starts typing, so when the UISearchController starts presenting results. This is all I get in the console :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MyProject.profileView: 0x13e9df000>  on <MyProject.SearchPage: 0x142a1d8f0> which is already presenting <UISearchController: 0x142a1f7c0>
```

That makes me think that the UISearchController is actually presenting a second UITableView with the filtered results over the first one, which I think should be what causes the bug. However, I'm not completely sure.

This is how I add the `UISearchController` to my `UIViewController` :

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Groups", "People"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

If you have any idea what could be causing this issue and/or how could I possibly fix it, I would really appreciate it if you could let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck on this issue for like 2 weeks I found out the solution was actually pretty easy. I just needed to present the `UIViewController` from the `UISearchController` rather than from the main `UIViewController`. This one line of code fixed it :

```
self.searchController.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```